# Stop vibrations

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, vibration

How do you stop the phone from vibrating when you use those system buttons (back, home, recent apps) in kitkat.

I tried perusing the settings,  but could not find any information relating to the same.

Or is this something in the design of the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Settings > Sounds` and uncheck `Vibrate on touch`.